# .load and .show/hide animations

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want a button that checks if a div is empty, and if empty loads my page into the div.  If the div is already visible I want it to become invisible again.  I know I can use toggle to do this, and the code I have below more or less works as desired:

```
function showChangeV(str)
{
var $output = $('#changev');
if( $output.is(':empty') )
    {
        $output.load("mydata.php",true);
        $output.hide();
    }
    $output.toggle(400);
};
```

The only issue I have is that the toggle function has a nice slide in/out animation when the button is clicked, but the intial load function does not.  Is there a way I can make the initial data load with a nice slide in animation in the same way the toggle does?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve the nice slide in animation? Can you share that with us?

Comment: The button performs the animation every time it toggles (ie when the button is clicked for the second, third, fourth etc time)  The only time it doesn't work is on the first click, ie the intial load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your question. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/2R3Vk/

```
function showChangeV(str) {
    var $output = $('#changev');
    if ($output.is(':empty')) {
        $output.html( $('.fakeLoad').text() ).show(1200);
    } else {
        $output.toggle(400);
    }
};
```

For your purposes replace this -

```
$output.html( $('.fakeLoad').text() ).show(1200);
```

with this -

```
$output.load("mydata.php", function() {
    $(this).show(1200); // animation will not run until the load is complete
});
```

You can change the `show()` speed to whatever you would like it to be.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry it took so long to accept the answer!